# Tomcat can't find Spring controller

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, intellij-idea, spring-boot

I am trying to set up a very small test project with SpringMVC.
I have managed to make it work running the jar file created in the target folder as explained in [this tutorial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5IhSl.png). However, I am not able to deploy a war file through the IntelliJ IDEA configuration.

Application:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {        
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

HelloController

```
@Controller
public class HelloController {
    @RequestMapping("/greeting")
    public String greeting(final Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("name", "bla");
        return "greeting";
    }
}
```

greeting.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Getting Started: Serving Web Content</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
</head>
<body>
    <p th:text="'Hello, ' + ${name} + '!'"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Run configuration:
[image: Run configuration]

Artifact:

[image: Artifact]
Structure and target output

[image: Structure and target output]

I am getting a 404 when going to "localhost:8080/greeting".

I'd be very glad if someone could point out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Have you followed [the instructions](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-create-a-deployable-war-file) for creating a deployable war file?

Comment: have you tried localhost:8080/testwebapp/greeting ?

Comment: Spring Boot applications are normally not built as WAR files, but as stand-alone JAR files. Is there a special reason why you are making a WAR file out of this, or did you just not know that you normally don't make a WAR out of a Spring Boot application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested on [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37836034/tomcat-cant-find-spring-controller?noredirect=1#comment63134082_37836034), I took a look at [these instructions](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-create-a-deployable-war-file). I was missing something in my Application.java, namely:

```
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(final SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I can see you start Spring as standalong application

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
```

Tomcat work only with servlet applications. Start your spring app as usual console app (In Idea in main() method right click and select 'run' menu item). 
Then request in browser `http://localhost:8080/greeting`

[spring-boot example](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/)

You don't need artifact in IDEA at all to start app.

So if you want to run Spring boot as war in servlet container like Tomcat then read [this doc](https://spring.io/guides/gs/convert-jar-to-war/)